# HTML/Javascript/JSP/JSTL: How to simulate browsers' back button with POST data?

Tags: javascript, jsp, post, jstl, back

I'm using a POST instead of GET to query data because I have way too many parameters and the url wouldn't look nice. I noticed my browser's (Chrome) back button is able to go back to the previous page generated by the previous POST.

I would like to add a button that simulates this behavior using HTML/Javascript/JSP/JSTL or backend Java if necessary. Any suggestions?

Example:

User is on home page, does a POST with parameter set S1.

User is taken to new page loaded from POST with parameter set S1. User does another POST with 
parameter set S2.

User is taken to new page loaded from POST with parameter set S2.

At this point, I want my back button to take the user back to the page resulting from a POST with parameter set S1. Do I have to save and pass on my current POST params to achieve this effect, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the method used is:

```
<!-- in header: ->
<script>
function goBack()
  {
  window.history.back()
  }
</script>
<!-- in body ->
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="goBack()">
```

But this is not the best method for doing so. Usually if databases and form submitting is used you should keep the variables in sessions so if you press a button you post again the variable last used.

Comment: i tried this but it just takes me to the previous page without the post parameters, which differs from what the browser back button does. I need users to be able to go back to their previous search.

Answer (score 0):

Well: I worked it around. Think this is what you want. On first klicking the Search button. It sets the session. On Second search, it resets the session to first search term. Back buton then uses first search term to "Go Back" 1 step. This only is good for 1 going back. Aka undo ONLY 1 search. Customize for your needs, and let me know was this what you wanted.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("db.php");

if(isset($_POST['searchterm'])) {
    if($_SESSION['oldsearch'] == "") {
        $_SESSION['oldsearch'] = $_POST['searchterm'];
    } else {
    $_SESSION['oldsearch'] = $_POST['oldsearch'];
    }
    $searchterm = $_POST['searchterm'];
} else if (isset($_POST['back1'])) {
    $_SESSION['oldsearch'] = $_POST['back'];
    $searchterm = $_POST['back'];
} else {    
    $_SESSION['oldsearch'] = "";
    $searchterm = "";
}


    if(isset($_POST['searchterm']) || isset($_POST['back1']) ) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kliendid WHERE name LIKE '%$searchterm%'"); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "Found from database: ".$row['name']."<br>";
    }
    }


?>

<form name="back" id="back" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="back" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['oldsearch']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="back1" id="back1" value="Back">
</form>

<form name="search" id="search" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="oldsearch" id="oldsearch" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['oldsearch']; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="searchterm" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="Search">
</form>
```